# Find $\int \frac{x^5}{x^3+3x^2+3x+1}\:\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus

> Find  $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{x^5}{x^3+3x^2+3x+1}\:\mathrm{d}x$.

I see that the denominator can we factored as $(x+1)^3$, but I don't see where to go from there.

Comment: you did the hard work. do the sub $u = x+1$ and expand the numerator.

Comment: @Chinny84 What do you mean by expand the numerator?

Comment: When you make the substitution $u=x+1$, the numerator becomes $(u-1)^5$. So expand that out using binomial.

Comment: Partial fractions.

Answer (score 5):

There are two reasonable ways of doing this. First, using partial fractions, one gets
$$\frac{x^5}{(x+1)^3} = x^2-3 x + 6 -\frac{10}{x+1}+\frac{5}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^3},$$
which can easily be integrated. Second, as @Chinny84 points out, if you substitute $u = x+1$, you get
$$\frac{x^5}{(x+1)^3} = \frac{(u-1)^5}{u^3} = u^2 - 5u + 10 - \frac{10}{u} + \frac{5}{u^2} - \frac{1}{u^3}.$$
Integrate with respect to $u$ and resubstitute $u = x+1$.

Comment: $\displaystyle x^2-3 x-\frac{10}{x+1}+\frac{5}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^3} + 6$ seems like an odd way to write it.  I'd have written $\displaystyle\underbrace{x^2-3 x+6}_{\text{quotient}} {} + {} \underbrace{ \frac{-10}{x+1}+\frac{5}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^3}}_{\text{remainder}}$.  Are you thinking of this in some other way than as involving a quotient and a remainder? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, just copy-pasted what Mathematica gave me. Fixed.

Comment: I suppose I should say that the remainder is the numerator in a fraction of the form $\dfrac{\text{something}}{(x+1)^3}$, before that gets broken into partial fractions.  The thing I've labeled "remainder" is what one deduces from knowing what the remainder is. ${}\qquad{}$